How to optimise an aggregation function with conditions?
I have an aggregation function that sums groups of data then creates a flag based on a set of conditions and assigns that to the group. The issue is that there is a large number of groups to aggregate and each group is very small.
This means that the time required to perform an aggregate, even for a modest-sized dataset, is prohibitively long and this needs to work on datasets with millions of rows.
I've created a reproducible example below which illustrates the problem and has a similar style of logic to my aggregation function (mine has more conditions, but they're similar in nature):
#install.packages("palmerpenguins")
library(data.table)
library(palmerpenguins)

# Create data
GROUPS <- 1:100
penguin_list <- lapply(GROUPS, \(x) data.table(group = x, penguins))
penguin_table <- rbindlist(penguin_list)

# Aggregation function
aggregatePenguinMass <- function(mass, sex, ratio = 2/3){
    data <- data.table(mass, sex)
    
    total <- sum(data[,mass], na.rm = TRUE)
    
    n_sex <- data[,.N, by = sex]
    n_male <- n_sex[sex == "male", N]
    n_female <- n_sex[sex == "female", N]
    
    if(n_female >= ratio * (n_male + n_female)){
        return(data.table(total = total,
                          flag = "F"))
    } else {
        return(data.table(total = total,
                          flag = "M"))
    }
}

# Perform aggregation and time
system.time(
penguin_table[, aggregatePenguinMass(body_mass_g, sex), by = .(group, species, year)]
)

#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.66    0.47    7.30 

How can I change this function or the way I'm performing the aggregation to make it an order of magnitude faster?

Benchmarks
Unit: milliseconds
         expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval
       base() 1793.4883 1803.1108 2491.32386 1821.8588 1928.4540 8195.9058    10
 RBarradas1() 1554.5428 1577.5579 1614.60087 1583.7645 1637.0681 1764.4564    10
 RBarradas2()  119.5481  127.6831  186.11583  131.7930  141.9157  657.2762    10
    NGraham()   23.2437   23.8428   25.50738   24.5770   27.4004   30.6569    10
       Miff()  427.2106  440.3240  462.32146  455.1878  462.6939  577.3803    10


A optimization is to sum(mass, na.rm = TRUE) instead of creating a data.table then subsetting and summing the extracted vector.

Could you provide bigger and more realistic data?

I think you want to avoid building as many data.tables as you have groups, and work with one large data.table only.
I can reproduce your aggregation with dtyplr (as I'm not so practiced in data.table syntax).
that looks like
library(dtplyr)

agg_dtyplr <- function(dt,mass, ratio = 2 / 3) {
  
  lazy_dt(dt) |> group_by(group, species, year)   |>
    summarise(
       total = sum({{mass}}, na.rm = TRUE),
    
       n_female = sum(1 * (sex == "female"),na.rm=TRUE),
       n = n())|> 
      mutate(
       flag = if_else(n_female >= ratio * n,
         "F", "M"
       )
     ) |> 
    select(group,species,year,total,flag) |> 
   as.data.table()
}

  agg_dtyplr(penguin_table,body_mass_g)


You don't need 1* in 1 * (sex == "female"). Internally, the condition becomes zeros or ones.

yes, I wrote it more verbose than needed ; the main idea is to use a single data.table;

A couple faster options. Option 1:
ratio <- 2/3
r <- 2 - ratio

jblood1 <- function() {
  penguin_table[, s := match(sex, c("female", "male"))][
    ,.(total = sum(body_mass_g, na.rm = TRUE),
       flag = if(mean(s, na.rm = TRUE) > r) "M" else "F"),
    .(group, species, year)
  ]
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  base(),
  jblood1(),
  check = "equal",
  times = 10
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>       expr      min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
#>     base() 1546.044 1554.1209 1582.18637 1569.23260 1606.2057 1661.9998    10
#>  jblood1()    7.428    7.5738   10.16692    8.15465   11.2894   20.9406    10

Option 2 is even faster by avoiding the grouping operations altogether with a sort, at the expense of additional complexity:
jblood2 <- function() {
  setorder(penguin_table, group, species, year)[
    , `:=`(csSex = cumsum(c(1, 1i, 0)[match(sex, c("female", "male", NA))]),
           csMass = fcumsum(body_mass_g))
  ][
    (grp <- rleid(group, species, year)) != shift(grp, -1, 0L),
    .(group, species, year, total = diff(c(0, csMass)),
      flag = fifelse(Im(d <- diff(c(0, csSex)))/Re(d) > 1/ratio - 1, "M", "F"))
  ]
}

all.equal(setorder(jblood1(), group, species, year), jblood2())
#> [1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  jblood1(),
  jblood2()
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>       expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
#>  jblood1() 7.2552 7.45605 8.469040 7.75345 8.21155 12.9634   100
#>  jblood2() 2.6411 2.82530 3.122956 3.06550 3.37760  4.5615   100


Was benchmarking with bigger data (34 million rows) and fcumsum(...) overflows but worked with  as.integer64(body_mass_g).

Or use as.numeric (and subtract off the mean for better precision with very large datasets). Or notice that body_mass_g is in increments of 25, so integer divide by 25L, then multiply by 25L at the end.

It looks to be quicker working with dplyr in this case:
Original version
system.time(
  a<- penguin_table[, aggregatePenguinMass(body_mass_g, sex), by = .(group, species, year)]
)

#user  system elapsed 
#1.45    0.47    1.61 

Using dplyr
Including a couple of optimisations in the summing
library(dplyr)

aggregatePenguinMass2 <- function(mass, sex, ratio = 2/3){
  total <- sum(mass, na.rm = TRUE)
  n_sex <- table(sex)

  n_male <- n_sex["male"]
  n_female <- n_sex["female"]
  
  if(n_female >= ratio * sum(n_sex)){
    return(data.table(total = total,
                      flag = "F"))
  } else {
    return(data.table(total = total,
                      flag = "M"))
  }
}

system.time(
 b <- penguin_table %>% summarise(aggregatePenguinMass2(body_mass_g, sex), .by = c(group, species, year))
)

#user  system elapsed 
#0.19    0.00    0.19 

all.equal(as.data.frame(a), b)
#[1] TRUE

A conversion to data.table at the end makes little difference to the timing if it's important to have the output in that format.

Here is a faster function.
It doesn't create and then subset data, It works directly on the input vectors.
library(data.table)
library(palmerpenguins)

# Create data
GROUPS <- 1:100
penguin_list <- lapply(GROUPS, \(x) data.table(group = x, penguins))
penguin_table <- rbindlist(penguin_list)

# Aggregation function (OP)
aggregatePenguinMass <- function(mass, sex, ratio = 2/3){
  data <- data.table(mass, sex)
  
  total <- sum(data[,mass], na.rm = TRUE)
  
  n_sex <- data[,.N, by = sex]
  n_male <- n_sex[sex == "male", N]
  n_female <- n_sex[sex == "female", N]
  
  if(n_female >= ratio * (n_male + n_female)){
    return(data.table(total = total,
                      flag = "F"))
  } else {
    return(data.table(total = total,
                      flag = "M"))
  }
}

# Aggregation function 2
aggregatePenguinMass2 <- function(mass, sex, ratio = 2/3){
  i <- !is.na(mass) & !is.na(sex)  
  total <- sum(mass[!is.na(mass)])
  
  f <- sum(sex[i] == "female")  
  if(f >= ratio * total){
    data.table(total = total, flag = "F")
  } else {
    data.table(total = total, flag = "M")
  }
}

# Perform aggregation and time
system.time(
  res <- penguin_table[, aggregatePenguinMass(body_mass_g, sex), by = .(group, species, year)]
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.41    0.08    2.40

system.time(
  res2 <- penguin_table[, aggregatePenguinMass2(body_mass_g, sex), by = .(group, species, year)]
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.04    0.00    0.11

all.equal(res, res2)
#> [1] TRUE

Created on 2024-07-11 with reprex v2.1.0

Using collapse with Rcpp:
library(collapse)
penguin_table |>
  fgroup_by(group, species, year) |>
  fsummarise(total = fsum(body_mass_g, na.rm = TRUE), flag = create_flag(sex))

Or alternatively with data.table (slower on the data given but might scale better (?))
penguin_table[, .(sum(body_mass_g, na.rm = TRUE), flag = create_flag(sex)),
              .(group, species, year)]

Where
Rcpp::cppFunction("char create_flag(const SEXP sex_vector, const double ratio = 2.0 / 3.0) {
  int m = 0;
  int f = 0;
  
  const R_xlen_t n = XLENGTH(sex_vector);
  const int* sex_ptr = INTEGER(sex_vector);
  
  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int val = sex_ptr[i];
    if (val == NA_INTEGER) {
      continue;
    } else if (val == 1) {
      f += 1;
    } else {
      m += 1;
    }
  }
  
  return (f >= ratio * (f + m)) ? 'F' : 'M';
}")

Benchmarks
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  op = penguin_table[, aggregatePenguinMass(body_mass_g, sex), by = .(group, species, year)],
  sb = penguin_table |>
    fgroup_by(group, species, year) |>
    fsummarise(total = fsum(body_mass_g, na.rm = TRUE), flag = create_flag(sex)),
  sbdt = penguin_table[, .(sum(body_mass_g, na.rm = TRUE), flag = create_flag(sex)),
                       .(group, species, year)],
  times = 10
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
#    op 1421.3494 1475.1812 1495.12772 1510.03970 1528.2198 1537.4873    10
#    sb    1.7398    1.7904    1.91444    1.84415    1.9116    2.5670    10
#  sbdt    3.3524    3.3710    3.78065    3.62835    4.1727    4.6842    10

